# difficult: How to get whatever the user inputs in a list to be printed such that no element is left out?

Tags: python, string, list

I've spent hours trying to figure this out but kept getting errors and am clueless on how to proceed.
Basically I am trying to make a bot that allows you to order one or two dishes in either a category of vietnamese dish or italian dish or both of the same kind. For the part I'm stuck on, I have to make an input function, such that the user types in whatever food they want in the form "["dish"] followed by typing in whatever price they want for that dish ["price"].

---

This is what the output screen is supposed to look like: (stuff typed in [] beside ==> is what the user types)

- Input the lists exactly using this format ["dish"]

```
Lists should have at least 1 dish and not more than 10 dishes 

Lists with prices correspond exactly to lists with dishes 

Execute with new lists (n) or original lists (o)? ==> n 

List of Vietnamese dishes ==> ["water", "rice", "pancake", "steamed sticky rice"] 
List of Vietnamese dishes prices ==> [7.5, 6.75, 5.15, 8.25] 
List of Italian dishes ==> ["pizza", "meatball spaghetti", "pasta"] 
List of Italian dishes prices ==> [7.15, 6.25, 5.0] 
*** TRACE Vietnamese  ['Pho', 'Fried rice', 'Pancake', 'Steamed sticky rice'] [7.5, 6.75, 5.15, 8.25] 
*** TRACE Italian  ['Pizza', 'Meatball spaghetti', 'Pasta'] [7.15, 6.25, 5.0] 


Order a dish? y/n ==> (y) 
All the available dishes are 
============================ 
v1 ‐ Pho 
v2 ‐ Fried rice 
v3 ‐ Pancake 
v4 ‐ Steamed sticky rice 
============================ 
i1 ‐ Pizza 
i2 ‐ Meatball spaghetti 
i3 ‐ Pasta 
============================
```

displays this:

```
==================================
v1  - cat

==================================

i1  - cadt
v2  - doh

==================================

i2  - dosh
v3  - dfd

==================================
```

when i use the following code

```
if (1 < a < 10 and 1 < b <10):
        for i in range(1,a+1) and range(1,b+1):
            print("v"+str(i)," -", vietnamese_dishes[i-1])
            print("\n==================================\n")
            print("i"+str(i)," -", italian_dishes[i-1])
        print("\n\nPlease choose another dish by indicating the code that we provide")
        print("\nYou may order the same dish as before, if you want")
        print("\nIf you do not choose an existing dish we will choose one for you")
        return
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you have code you can share with us?

Comment: It's kind of a mess ill post it hold on

Comment: for (1 < a <10) that's where i got lost. I just stopped, i couldnt think anymore.

Comment: yes it is, im nearly done, just this part i really cant figure out

Comment: right at if (a == 1) and below, i am stuck

Comment: can you tell me what exactly you want in input.

Comment: all the stuff below "Order a dish? y/n ==> (y)   All the available dishes are" but for each of them i have to make it so that it only shows the dishes the user typed in also the prices they typed in

Answer (score 0):

Change the second `if` statement in `dish_codeslist` to this:

```
if (1 < a < 10):
        for i in range(1,a+1):
            print("v"+str(i)," -", vietnamese_dishes[i-1])
        print("\n\nPlease choose another dish by indicating the code that we provide")
        print("\nYou may order the same dish as before, if you want")
        print("\nIf you do not choose an existing dish we will choose one for you")
        return
```

EDIT:

```
    if (1 < a < 10):
        for i in range(1,a+1):
            print("v"+str(i)," -", vietnamese_dishes[i-1])
    print("\n==================================")
    if (1 < b < 10):
        for i in range(1,b+1):
            print("i"+str(i)," -", italian_dishes[i-1])
        print("\n\nPlease choose another dish by indicating the code that we provide")
        print("\nYou may order the same dish as before, if you want")
        print("\nIf you do not choose an existing dish we will choose one for you")
```

EDIT 2:

```
if (1 < a < 10 and 1 < b <10):
        for i in range(1,a+1):
            print("v"+str(i)," -", vietnamese_dishes[i-1])
        print("\n==================================\n")
        for i in range(1,b+1):
            print("i"+str(i)," -", italian_dishes[i-1])
        print("\n==================================\n")
        print("\n\nPlease choose another dish by indicating the code that we provide")
        print("\nYou may order the same dish as before, if you want")
        print("\nIf you do not choose an existing dish we will choose one for you")
        return
```

EDIT 3:

```
def dish_codeslist():
    a = len(vietnamese_dishes)
    b = len(italian_dishes)
    dish_dict = {}
    print("\n\nAll the available dishes are")
    print("\n==================================")
    if (a == 1):
        print("v"+str(a)," -", vietnamese_dishes[0])
        print("\n\nPlease choose another dish by indicating the code that we provide")
        print("\nYou may order the same dish as before, if you want")
        print("\nIf you do not choose an existing dish we will choose one for you")
        return
    if (1 < a < 10 and 1 < b <10):
        for i in range(1,a+1):
            print("v"+str(i)," -", vietnamese_dishes[i-1])
            dish_dict["v"+str(i)] = (vietnamese_dishes[i-1],vietnamese_dish_prices[i-1])
        print("\n==================================\n")
        for i in range(1,b+1):
            print("i"+str(i)," -", italian_dishes[i-1])
            dish_dict["i"+str(i)] = (italian_dishes[i-1],italian_dish_prices[i-1])
        print("\n==================================\n")
        return dish_dict
def choose_dish(dish_dict):
    print("\n\nPlease choose another dish by indicating the code that we provide")
    print("\nYou may order the same dish as before, if you want")
    print("\nIf you do not choose an existing dish we will choose one for you")
    choice = input("Provide the dish code here (MUST BE a letter and a number) ==> ")
    if choice in dish_dict.keys():
        print(f"*** TRACE: dish {dish_dict[choice][0]} price {dish_dict[choice][1]} ")
    else:
        print("You did not enter a valid choice, we will suggest a dish for you")
        import random
        dish = random.choice([*dish_dict.values()])
        print("*** TRACE: dish {dish[0]} price {dish[1]} ")
#### Start
codes_setup()
dish_dict = dish_codeslist()
choose_dish(dish_dict)
```

Comment: will it work for dishes say if the user selected 3 or 4 or 6 of either or both categories? as in will this be printed with a code along with the dish they input?

Comment: In that case  you will need to use a `dict` and a `while` loop if you want them to continue choosing dishes. And the codes you are mentioning need to be a `key` in a dictionary which will have the dishes as their `values`. For example, store each of the food items in their keys (i.e. their codes) when you are printing  the choices. and when they choose a dish with the code, access the that code in the dictionary.

Comment: for vietnamese_dishes[i-1] how do i make it so that it counts every element in the list. like lista = (dog,cat,cow) so v1 = dog,  v2 = cat,  v3 = cow and listb = (blue,red) so i1= blue, i2 = red. All of this, how print it?

Comment: Here it is calculating all of the elements in vietnamese_dishes. For italian dishes you need to check the length of italian_dishes list and store it in a variable let's say `b`, and then add another if check with `if (1 < b < 10):` and change all `a`s to `b`.

Comment: it worked but now when it shows the display list like:========= v1 = item i1 = item1 v2 = item3. How can I make the display list so the ========== separates the two group of items like shown in the code i displayed?

Comment: like it shows three separate lines ========== separating every two group of viet and ital dishes (when i put 6 items in total) how can i only make it so it shows one line ========== top being viet and bottom being ital

Comment: Change this: `print("\n==================================")` to this:
`print("\n==================================\n")`

Comment: You should put the itialian dishes in another if statement, not inside the previous if statement.

Comment: it still has four lines. I will post another display at the top for you to see

Comment: i posted the new display. it is the last two pictures. how can i make so that it shows a display like the first picture i posted

Comment: Edited again, please check.

Comment: it works now. I need one more step. When it shows "Provide the dish code here (MUST BE a letter and a number) ==> " how can I use the code that was printed along with the value/price to be inputted for this?

Comment: like it should print *** TRACE: dish (whatever) costs (value)

Answer (score 0):

```
# enter vietnames names dishes names here
vietnamese_dishes  = [input('enter the dish name: ') for i in range(int(input('how many dishes you want to put in vietnamese_dishes: ')))]

# enter the prices for corresponding vietnames dishes here 
vietnamese_dish_prices  = [int(input('enter the price for '+dish+ ': '))  for dish in vietnamese_dishes]

print(vietnamese_dishes)
print(vietnamese_dish_prices)

vietnames = [vietnamese_dishes, vietnamese_dish_prices]
print(vietnames)
```

this code may help to solve your problem, first give this a try by run it in a new python file

[image]

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[2]'   I entered 2 dishes with first dish being price [2]

Comment: it is because it does not accept the value in that format

Comment: try doing as you see in the image

Comment: how to format that so that it is the same as shown in the first code i provided like ============

Comment: wait doing that stuff, but if you want you can use this it a simple kind of thing

Comment: it worked but i want to know how to format it the way i showed in the code i first posted

Comment: hey, can you please elaborate to me to be more specific about what would you want to do like how user are gonna interact

Answer (score 0):

```
def user_input(user_list):
    print("Enter the dish that you want to order")
    user_value = input()
    user_list.append(user_value)
    print(user_list)
    print("Do u want to add more dishes: ")
    answer = input()
    if answer == "Yes":
        user_input(user_list)
        return user_list
    else:
        return user_list
#### Start
codes_setup()
dish_codeslist()
user_list=[]
modified_list = user_input(user_list)
print("The modified new list is :")
print(modified_list)
```

Add this piece of code to your code and try running it to see whether it satisfies your requirements. The handling of user inputs whether they input the dish from any category gets added to a new list in this piece of code.